# django raises AttributeError when calling _set.all() for its child model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently imitating django official polls example to develop my own model like following:

```
from django.db import models

class Instance(models.Model):
    inst_host = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.inst_host

class RDMInfo(models.Model):
    instance = models.ForeignKey(Instance)
    filesystem = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    osdevice = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    lun_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    lun_id = models.IntegerField()
    wwn = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    lun_size = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.filesystem, self.osdevice, self.lun_name, self.lun_id, self.wwn, self.lun_size)
```

and when I do following actions the error occurred:

```
>>> from rdm.models import Instance, RDMInfo
>>> q = Instance.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q
<Instance: alps_mtkalpsdbp1>
>>> q.rdminfo_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __repr__
    return repr(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 496, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/home/oracle/jrlin/smc/rdm/models.py", line 17, in __str__
    return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.filesystem, self.osdevice, self.lun_name, self.lun_id, self.wwn, self.lun_size)
AttributeError: 'RDMInfo' object has no attribute 'inst_host'
```

In the official example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Its Question and Choice models work fine, and the structure of mine is almost identical to the example

Does anyone know why the error raised? Thanks!

> Update

I also configured the django admin as follows, will such action lead to the error?

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Instance, RDMInfo

class RDMInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RDMInfo
    extra = 1

class RDMAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['inst_host']
    inlines = [RDMInline]

admin.site.register(Instance, RDMAdmin)
```

**Solved**

Thanks for everyone's comment, it's my mistake, originally I typo and an unwanted attribute "self.inst_host" appears in the return command of the RDMInfo model, and after I remove it, I should execute migrate again and reopen the python shell. After doing migration and reopen the shell, it works find, thanks!

Comment: There's no reason the code you posted would raise this error. Are you sure you didn't have a previous version of the code already imported in your Python/Django shell ?  Does the error persist if you close your shell and restart it ?

Comment: I just executed the code to check, as mentioned by @brunodesthuilliers says, it works. Guess you have some other mixed up old model or data somewhere !

Comment: I have tried to remove the whole project and recreate then did it again but the same error persists.